# codeigniter mysql active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  numrows 
FROM (
books
)
WHERE (
id_status =1
OR id_status =2
)
AND  company =2
```

how to convert to CI Active Record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as numrows')->from('books ')->where("(id_status='1' OR id_status='2') and company ='2'")
```

Comment: If the result is enough can use `count_all_results` instead of `select` and can split `where` into two parts.